# logging system for nodejs and node-worker

Tags: javascript, logging, node.js

nodejs logging system, I want a beautiful console logging and also can save to log file, and also fast, async will be better.

The most difficult is , [node-worker](https://github.com/cramforce/node-worker), which use std io to communicate with parent process, so if the logging system using std io, it can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of options given on [this page](https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/modules#debugging), in the debugging section.

Comment: They can if they can write to files. Either use a logfile per worker, or set the workers to send their messages to a single process, with a stream socket or a pipe or syslog.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked through many loggers, and I wasn't able to find a lightweight solution - so I decided to make a simple solution that is posted on github.

- Saves the file
- Gives you a pretty output (we all love that)

I hope this helps you out.

**SETUP**

```
https://github.com/bluejamesbond/Scribe.js
```

*PS: If there are any problems, I would be obliged if you can fix it and then do a pull request. Otherwise, you are more than welcome to post as an issue.*

**SAMPLE OUTPUT TO CONSOLE**

[image]

**SAMPLE DIRECTORY SETUP**

[image]

**SAMPLE OUTPUT FILE**

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this works with `node-worker`. I feel that it should be easy to implement a queue that builds the outputs and then prints out as necessary.